# @if directive can't use string var from js

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the table with field accept (type boolean).`@If` directive must display other button depends of value of accept field. It look like this:

```
@if($accept == 1)
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Remove ads  {{ $accept }}</a>
@else
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Accept ads {{ $accept }}</a>
@endif
```

Accept var is share by js. It look like this:

```
 html += `@include('include.singleads', ['cover' => "` + item.cover + `", 'title' => "` +item.title+ `", 'accept' => "` +item.accept+ `", 'description' => "` +item.description+ `"])`;
```

Problem is that accept (1 or 0) is display correctly next to title of button but `@if` directive doesn't work. I know that `$accept` is a string but if I remove quote this code doesn't work. I tried change the type (use intval()) but then `$accept` has only 0 value.

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Try `(int) $accept`

Comment: I tryed that but  in this cas it shouldn't matter becouse I use "==" not "===". I trued put in quotation marks value `@if($accept == "1")` but problem is this same.

Comment: Can you post the result of var_dump($accept)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of Type Cast as below:

```
$accept = (int) $accept //to convert it into integer
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

Comment: I tryed `@php ($accept = (int) $accept)`. Problem is this same like in the case of intval(). So all accept value is replace to 0. I I use this in @if directive (it doesn't matter that I use intval or (int)) it display success button.

Comment: I tryed but it shouldn't matter becouse I use "==" not "==="